# How to log into a restricted site

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I am doing some summer research with my school. I have to download ~2000 images off of a restricted site with graphs. I could absolutely do this manually, but I know it would be much faster to do with some sort of script. I've settled on Python, because I am assuming it will be much easier than another language. I have the URL for the site and the generic link for the database where the images are stored. I plan to feed the program a list of orbit numbers and it will download the appropriate images. The main issue is that when you visit the site, it pops up a login window through the browser, not HTML. I cannot view any of the site code to see how to submit the login.

I have already tried to use urllib and cookielib. I realize that urllib2 does not work in Python 3. I have also looked into using requests and mechanize with no luck.

```
import cookielib
import urllib2
import string

def cook():
    url="SITE"
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    authinfo = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    realm="realmName"
    username="USERNAME"
    password="PASS"
    host="HOST"
    authinfo.add_password(realm, host, username, password)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), authinfo)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    # Create request object
    txheaders = { 'User-agent' : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)" }
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, None, txheaders)
        cj.add_cookie_header(req)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    except IOError as e:
        print("Failed to open", url)
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print("Error code:", e.code)

    else:

        print (f)
        print (f.read())
        print (f.info())
        f.close()
        print('Cookies:')
        for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
            print (index, " : ", cookie)      
        cj.save("cookies.lwp")
```

The code, obviously, just throws a bunch of errors. I really just need to be able to get into the site and download my images.

Comment: See this:http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @Noah Baker You can access it using ftp if it supports ftp

Comment: If you have the ftp password then you can do this easily

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selenium web driver to make login automate and download images. Read this [article](https://medium.com/@emery_44439/data-scraping-pdf-parsing-python-bot-15b97bb37785) it will help you to **scrape** data from login required website

Answer (score 0):

Totally was able to fix it by bypassing the verify. I know its not a great method, but it does what I need it to. Thanks guys!